# SSH, via a Jump Host, with a dynamic port number

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've got 3 hosts:

1. My computer.
2. A Jump Host (aka bastion) with a static IP.
3. A server with a dynamic IP; behind a NAT router/firewall, with no inbound ports open.

The server currently connects to the Jump Host, and establishes an SSH tunnel via `-R "0:localhost:22"`, so the port is dynamically allocated by the Jump Host (this has been very reliable so far).

With some [socket magic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585151/251179), I have the dynamically allocated port number recorded in a file on the Jump Host.

With this, I can SSH to the Jump Host, and run `ssh -p $(cat /path/to/port-file) localhost`

But is it possible to skip this extra step?

---

This would be useful for Ansible, where my `inventory.yml` needs to have the port number updated:

```
server:
  # /usr/bin/ssh jh cat /path/to/port-file
  ansible_port: "34625"
  ansible_host: "localhost"
  ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o ProxyCommand='ssh -q -W %h:%p jh' -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

---

It might be possible to use `ProxyCommand`:

It can (sort-of) use command substitution on my computers `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host server
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W localhost:$(echo "34625") jh
```

This works (even without `echo -n`) where the substitution seems to happen on my local computer.

And despite the inefficiency of using SSH to get the port number first, this doesn't work:

```
Host server
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W localhost:$(ssh jh cat /path/to/port-file) jh
```

It results in:

```
Bad packet length 1349676916.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: message authentication code incorrect
```

And oddly, the server (at the end of the chain), does note this in its auth logs:

```
sshd[5558]: Bad protocol version identification '' from ::1 port 36048
```

Which implies that the port number is being returned. But no idea why it breaks at this point.

And `ssh -vvv` shows that it identifies the hostkey in my `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

---

I've also tried creating a custom "ssh_config" file on the Jump Host, using `ssh -F /path/to/ssh_config`, with the contents:

```
Host tunnel.server
  HostName localhost
  Port 34625
```

But I don't think I can use this with the `ProxyCommand`.

---

I also suspect `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` might be need to be introduced at some point, when the port number changes.

Comment: Why a *random* port, and not, say, a *fixed* unix socket name?

Comment: @anx; Originally I used a fixed port number, and I found that when the connection dropped (very unreliable connection), on re-connect it would often fail because the port was still in use (I assume the ssh process on the Jump Host hadn’t closed it yet, and even with ConnectTimeout / ServerAliveInterval / ServerAliveCountMax, it still had issues)... so I suspect the socket approach will have the same issue?

Comment: Unix sockets behave a lot like files. Remove the old one and you are free to create a new one with precisely the same name. That is what the option `StreamLocalBindUnlink` is for.

Comment: Thanks @anx, that's a good point, I'll have a go at that on the weekend.

Comment: @anx, Thanks again, I've been able to get socket files to work, using details from https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451788/251179 ... but due to permission issues (I get the tunnel established by a low level account, which also uses rbash, where StreamLocalBindMask does not seem to work on my system), plus the socket file being a bit odd when trying to delete it (StreamLocalBindUnlink does not seem to fix)... so I'll stick with normal ports for now. But really useful to know this is now possible since OpenSSH 6.7.

Comment: @anx, Correction, StreamLocalBindMask and StreamLocalBindUnlink needs to be set on the servers `sshd_config`... while these options can be set when connecting (e.g. `ssh -o 'StreamLocalBindMask=0111'`) I believe that's only used when creating socket files on the client, not the server (so I'll need to use something like `Match User tunnel`, to keep the default of 0177 for other use cases).

Answer (score 1):

Second partial solution, inspired by @anx...

Create a socket file

```
ssh -R '/path/to/socket-file:localhost:22' tunnel@jh
```

Then, to use this socket (from the Jump Host), I can use `socat`:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/path/to/socket-file" localhost
```

The use of `socat` seems like an unnecessary step, where I'm sure there must be a way to get the `ssh` command to use the socket file directly, but I can't find it yet.

I've also not found how to use this socket file from my computer (as ProxyCommand is run on localhost, not on the JumpHost).

I should also note; as the `tunnel` account (on the Jump Host) is very restricted (it's only there to establish these tunnel connections), I need to set `StreamLocalBindMask=0111` so my account on the Jump Host can use this socket file. Likewise, the old socket file should be removed if a new connection is established, via `StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes`.

Both of these options need to be set on the Jump Host, in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config":

```
Match User tunnel
  StreamLocalBindMask 0111
  StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
```

Unfortunately `Match` rules are ignored in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/tunnel.conf" before OpenSSH 8.4, released September 27 2020 ([bug report](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3122)), and this isn't currently available on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Use `ssh -o "ProxyCommand=ssh jumphost netcat -U /path/to/socket" destination` to use it remotely - thats the ssh connection to the destination piped through the socket, through netcat/socat/whatever, through the stdin/stdout of your regular ssh connection to the jumphost. Not sure why ssh does not allow sockets out of the box in `JumpHost`, `HostName` and `-w` but one day it will. Until then, the longer cmdline is functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution, not ideal...

Add an hourly cron job on my computer, it collects the port number(s) from the Jump Host, and creates a new `~/.ssh/config_tunnels` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u;

config_path="${HOME}/.ssh/config_tunnels";

port=$(/bin/ssh jh /bin/cat /path/to/port-file 2> /dev/null | /bin/sed 's/[^0-9]//g');
if [[ "${port}" -lt 1024 ]]; then
  exit; # Probably a blank/zero value (e.g. connection issue).
fi
    
{
  echo "";
  echo "Host server";
  echo "  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W localhost:${port} jh";
  echo "";
} > "${config_path}";

chown user:group "${config_path}";
chmod 600 "${config_path}";
```

The main `~/.ssh/config` file can then use `Include ~/.ssh/config_tunnels`.

Note, I'm using `sed` to be sure I'm getting a number back. If my Jump Host was to be compromised, I don't want the port-file to contain some extra (malicious) SSH config.